# Solve the 2nd order ODE IVP using method undetermined coefficients

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, initial-value-problems

The given equation and values are 
$$y^{"}-2y^{'}+y=10e^x$$
$$y(0)=4 \space , y^{'}(0)=2$$
Finding the root's is easy enough:
$$(m^2-2m+1)=0$$
$$m_1=1$$
Then our Aux. Equ. is:
$$y_c=C_1e^x+C_2xe^x$$
Then because our Aux. contains an $xe^x$ term, our $y_p=Ax^2e^x$. Taking the second derivative and solving for $A$:
$$y^{''}=Ax^2e^x+4Axe^x+2Ae^x$$
Now plugging into $y^{''}-2y^{'}-y=10e^x$ and solving yields:
$$10e^x=2Ae^x$$
$$10=2A$$
$$A=5$$
Now we have our $y_p=5x^2e^x$, that plus our $y_c$ equals $y$:
$$y=C_1e^x+C_2xe^x+5x^2e^x$$ 
Solving the IVP yields:
$$4=C_1e^0+C_2(0)e^0+5(0)^2e^0$$
$$4=C_1$$
$$2=4e^x+C_2xe^x+10xe^x+5x^2e^x$$
$$2=4+C_2$$
$$-2=C_2$$
So the final answer is:
$$y=4e^x-2xe^x+5x^2e^x$$
Are my calculations correct and my execution flawless? 
P.S. : I do realize that the variable should have changed to $t$ but the issue seems negligible.

Comment: It seems easier to do with Laplace transform.

Comment: Looks correct to me. You used undetermined coefficients method not variation of parameter Eric

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks good to me.I, fact, you used  undetermined coefficients method instead of variation of parameter. You forgot also a term here :
$$2=4e^x+C_2xe^x+10xe^x+5x^2e^x$$
Should be
$$2=4e^x+C_2(xe^x+e^x)+10xe^x+5x^2e^x$$
$$  \implies C_2=-2$$